# Cross-origin request not setting cookies, reactJs, Django Backend, Firefox + Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I have a react app, and sending requests as such:

```
        const public_key_r = await axios.get(
      "https://eliptum.tech/get-public-key",
      {
        withCredentials: true, // This is crucial for cookies to be sent and received in cross-origin requests
      },
    );
    const publicKey = public_key_r.data.publicKey;
    const csrfToken = public_key_r.data.csrf_token;
    console.log(csrfToken);
    const encryptedPassword = await encryptData(password, publicKey, false);

    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://eliptum.tech/user/create",
      {
        username,
        encryptedPassword,
        email,
        phone_number: phoneNumber,
      },
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
        },
      },
    );
```

My Backed view for https://eliptum.tech/get-public-key get request is:

```
class PublicKeyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Ensure a session ID is available
        if not request.session.session_key:
            request.session.save()

        session_id = request.session.session_key

        private_key, public_key = RSAKeyManager.get_keys(session_id)
        if not private_key or not public_key:
            # Keys are generated as bytes, so decode them before storing
            private_key, public_key = RSAKeyManager.generate_keys()
            RSAKeyManager.store_keys(session_id, private_key.decode('utf-8'), public_key.decode('utf-8'))

        if isinstance(public_key, bytes):
            public_key = public_key.decode('utf-8')

        # Retrieve CSRF token
        csrf_token = get_token(request)

        # Construct the JSON response
        response_data = {
            "session_id": session_id,
            "public_key": public_key,
            "csrf_token": csrf_token
        }

        # Create JsonResponse with the response data
        response = JsonResponse(response_data, status=200)

        # Set CSRF token as a cookie in the response
        # Ensure the Secure and SameSite attributes are correctly set for cross-origin compatibility
        response.set_cookie('csrftoken', csrf_token, secure=True, samesite='None')
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        return response
```

Settings are:

```
"""
Django settings for django_backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

from utils.utils import get_secrets

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-&sru-aw9zw@2t*hyy7eh&ynb5buu(tw_sd7=xsgt(+6bi5&h4f"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "backend_app",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "django_backend.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "django_backend.wsgi.application"

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'eliptumr_users',
        'USER': 'eliptumr_db',
        'PASSWORD': get_secrets("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': 'servercp73.20x.host',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

SANDBOX = "https://7w37f9-3000.csb.app"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend_app.CustomUser'
INPUT_DATA_ENCRYPT = False
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'https://eliptum.tech',
    SANDBOX,
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['eliptum.tech', SANDBOX]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://eliptum.tech', SANDBOX]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['https://eliptum.tech', SANDBOX]
```

Added everything i could find to make cross origin work but, no, for:
    `const response = await axios.post( "https://eliptum.tech/user/create"`

Backend has django-cors-headers and `response.set_cookie('csrftoken', csrf_token, secure=True, samesite='None') response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'`

All requests have `withCredentials: true` for axios, not sure what's missing or what's not configured properly, if anything

Basically i have my backed at eliptum.tech host, and frontend on some sandbox, but there is no way for me to make em work together it seems

Not sure if you can access https://7w37f9-3000.csb.app/#, its the frontend that you could test what im saying, gotta select signin/signup and then signup with a random account

Issue is i cannot do the post request because:

```
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF cookie not set.
```

Which is fair considering no cookies are set :(

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that besides all that i ve added till now, in django settings
gotta add
`CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`